# I think I have a bug on updating my bots on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

When I update my bot, this comes up but I didn't download python 3.6.12 and I can't even find it on my bot file

````
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (from -r /tmp/build_b9062471/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py to /tmp/pip-req-build-w_uf5vjl
remote:        ERROR: Package 'discord.py' requires a different Python: 3.6.12 not in '>=3.8.0'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e57967648499af73119f798dd7a13a188b3a4d5e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e57967648499af73119f798dd7a13a188b3a4d5e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aarlibot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aarlibot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your application runs on Heroku on `Python 3.6.12` while the `discord` package demands at least 3.8.0.

The Python runtime is provided by Heroku (default these days is 3.9.7, but this depends on when you have created your application), it is anyhow possible to [define the version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version):

- create a `runtime.txt` file
- set the version `python-3.9.7`

Comment: Thx for the answer! I was finding for the answer but I couldn't and now I'm here.